# Convert mm-yy character string to a date in R

Tags: r, date, as.date

I have a data frame with a column containing dates in the format of mm/yy. However, the column is character type and I would like to change it to a date for plotting purposes.

Example code below:

```
x <- c("01/20","02/20","03/20")
as.Date(x,format = "%m/%y")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I would like to use as.Date if possible.

Comment: Does "01/20" stand for January, 2020, "02/20" stand for February 2020, and so on?

Comment: Try `as.Date(paste0('01/',x),format = "%d/%m/%y")`

Answer (score 0):

One way to address it would be to add characters and then pass it to as.Date

```
x <- c("01/20","02/20","03/20")
as.Date(paste0("01/",x),format = "%d/%m/%y")
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it suitable?

```
x <- c("01/20","02/20","03/20")
as.Date.character(paste0('01/', x), '%d/%m/%y')
[1] "2020-01-01" "2020-02-01" "2020-03-01"
```